# How to disambiguate symbolic regular expressions

Tags: formal-languages, reference-request, regular-languages, regular-expressions, ambiguity

What I mean by a "symbolic regular expression" (if there already is a different name for this I'm not aware of it) is a regular expression that may include exponents that are symbolic arithmetic expressions.

Example 1: $a^k|b^*$ means "either $k$ copies of $a$ or zero or more copies of $b$".
Example 2: $a^{k+1}|a^k$ means "either $k$ or $k+1$ copies of $a$".

What I'd like to do is disambiguate such regular expressions.  I know that to disambiguate a normal regular expression, you can convert it to an NFA, then a DFA, then back to a regular expression.

The problem is not completely straightforward.  For example, $a^k|a^j$ is ambiguous if $j=k$ and unambiguous otherwise.  Thus, the appropriate output would be, for example,
$$a^k \text{ if } k=j, \qquad a^k|a^j \text{ otherwise.}$$

Does anyone know if there has been anything written about this problem?

Comment: Hmmm. So, you might want to convert an expression such as $\bigl[(a^3)^\ast \mathrel| (a^5)^\ast\bigr]$ to $\bigl[\varepsilon \mathrel| a^3 \mathrel| a^5 \mathrel| a^6 \mathrel| a^8a^\ast\bigr]$, that is separating out all possibilities exhaustively into disjoint collections (a sort of sum-of-products)?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Yes, I would want to do that (except instead of 3 and 5 the exponents would be symbolic expressions).

Comment: Nota bene: there is hope, as [there is no inherently ambiguous regular language](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109/are-there-inherently-ambiguous-and-deterministic-context-free-languages). [This paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/inco.1997.2695) may provide an answer in a special case.

Comment: There is a problem: if you require a case analysis for all possible values of the symbolic exponents, an example such as I gave yields either an indeterminate number of disjuncts in the formula (it is not an augmented-regular-expression, but a *schema* for such expressions), or an infinite number of cases. If we consider $\bigl[(a^j)^\ast \mathrel| (a^k)^\ast\bigr]$, the number of disjuncts in the result doesn't just depend on whether $j=k$. For example, $k=nj+r$ (for $n,r\geqslant0$) has at least $\lcm(j,k)+1 = \frac{nj^2+rj}{\gcd(j,r)}+1$ disjuncts, which for $n,r,j$ arbitrary is unbounded.

Comment: I said the exponents may be "symbolic arithmetic expressions"; there are different classes of expression that could be allowed, e.g. just symbols or integers, polynomials, polynomials and exponentials, ...  I am interested in even the simplest case, such as in Niel's example above.

Comment: @AndrewMacFie: So, would you admit the answer $a^{\{uj + vk \,\mathrel|\, u,v \in \mathbb N\}}$? It's certainly unambiguous, and I'm not entirely sure how to address the example that I gave without also admitting something like that as a possible answer.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I'm not sure whether I would call that unambiguous or not.  Something "simpler" than that would be ideal.  That's a good question, though.  I'll think more about it.